# How to get user info given discord id using the discord Bot class?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the discord.ext.commands Bot class. I need to get user info from id's I have in a dictionary, so that I can send them direct messages. I know there is a method to get user info from id using the client class (the .get_user_info() ) function, however I am not using the client class, only the Bot class. Is there a way to get user info using the bot class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `user = bot.fetch_user(id)`. After this, you can access all the user's attributes through `user`, such as `user.display_name`.